# Replacing Header with Top Row

Tags: python, pandas, header, row

I currently have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Unnamed: 1    Unnamed: 2   Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4
0   Sample Number  Group Number  Sample Name  Group Name
1             1.0           1.0          s_1         g_1
2             2.0           1.0          s_2         g_1
3             3.0           1.0          s_3         g_1
4             4.0           2.0          s_4         g_2
```

I'm looking for a way to delete the header row and make the first row the new header row, so the new dataframe would look like this:

```
    Sample Number  Group Number  Sample Name  Group Name
0             1.0           1.0          s_1         g_1
1             2.0           1.0          s_2         g_1
2             3.0           1.0          s_3         g_1
3             4.0           2.0          s_4         g_2
```

I've tried stuff along the lines of `if 'Unnamed' in df.columns:` then make the dataframe without the header

```
df.to_csv(newformat, header=False, index=False)
```

but I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
```

Comment: When I do this, the 0 index is also becoming a part of the header. Is there a way to remove the 0 index from my header row?

Comment: @Pete What is the output that you get from `df.columns`?

Comment: @Pete, change `new_header = df.iloc[0]` to `new_header = df.iloc[0].tolist()`. This will remove the 0 index as part of the header.

Comment: @jb12n, I just want to say you were spot on.  And I will add you can go directly to setting the columns by using df.columns = df.iloc[0].tolist().  As I understand it iloc generated a Series the name of which is the index location.  Check by printing the type of new_header.  When you make a list you lose the name of the Series.  What I find interesting is that the documentation seems to ignore all this (at least I cannot find any).  So glad I happened on this thread today.

Answer (score 105):

The dataframe can be changed by just doing

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Then

```
df.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This is a bettter answer, because there is not redundant code (new_header) in this.

Answer (score 74):

If you want a one-liner, you can do:

```
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
```

Comment: Make it `df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)` if you don't want your index to be missing something.

Comment: did work for me after making it a two-liner '
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0, :], inplace=True)
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)

Answer (score 20):

Another one-liner using Python swapping:

```
df, df.columns = df[1:] , df.iloc[0]
```

This won't reset the index

Although, the opposite won't work as expected `df.columns, df = df.iloc[0], df[1:]`

Comment: how does the assignment work? Is df first assigned or df.columns?

Comment: This answer explains it great https://stackoverflow.com/a/34171485/11808854

Answer (score 10):

@ostrokach answer is best.  Most likely you would want to keep that throughout any references to the dataframe, thus would benefit from inplace = True.
    `df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0], inplace = True)
df.drop([0], inplace = True)`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple trick that defines column indices "in place". Because `set_index` sets *row* indices in place, we can do the same thing for columns by transposing the data frame, setting the index, and transposing it back:

```
df = df.T.set_index(0).T
```

Note you may have to change the `0` in `set_index(0)` if your rows have a different index already.

Comment: best solution. elegant.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, we can do this when reading a file with pandas.

This case we can use,

```
pd.read_csv('file_path',skiprows=1)
```

When reading the file this will skip the first row and will set the column as the second row of the file.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The values in the second row are not supposed to be the header values. In fact, this is basically the reverse of what the solution should be. If skiprows=-1 would cause the first row to be used as the header, that would be the solution. The accepted solution accomplishes the goal.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, I had to do it this way:

```
df.columns = [*df.iloc[0]]
df = table[1:]
```

The part where I'm splitting the list into a list looks redundant, but otherwise, the headers still turn up as part of the actual table.

Comment: You just missed that table does not exists, it would be 'df' too

Answer (score 1):

--another way to do this

```py
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0)).reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns.name = None

    Sample Number  Group Number  Sample Name  Group Name
0             1.0           1.0          s_1         g_1
1             2.0           1.0          s_2         g_1
2             3.0           1.0          s_3         g_1
3             4.0           2.0          s_4         g_2
```

If you like it hit up arrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
header = table_df.iloc[0]
table_df.drop([0], axis =0, inplace=True)
table_df.reset_index(drop=True)
table_df.columns = header
table_df
```

Comment: Please add an explanation

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task that may be needed more than once. I've taken rgalbo's answer and written a simple function that can be lifted and placed into any project.

```
def promote_df_headers(df):
    '''
    Takes a df and uses the first row as the header

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : DataFrame
        Any df with one or more columns.

    Returns
    -------
    df : DataFrame
        Input df with the first row removed and used as the column names.

    '''

    new_header = df.iloc[0] 
    df = df[1:] 
    df.columns = new_header
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with a list of lists

`pd.DataFrame(input[1:], columns=input[0])`

Answer (score -4):

The best practice and **Best OneLiner**:

```
df.to_csv(newformat,header=1)
```

Notice the header value:

Header refer to the Row number(s) to use as the column names. Make no mistake, the row number is not the df but from the excel file(0 is the first row, 1 is the second and so on).

This way, you will get the column name you want and won't have to write additional codes or create new df.

Good thing is, it drops the replaced row.

Comment: This just outputs CSV though, it doesn't change the dataframe, right?

Comment: @AMC bit late in replying. To answer you question, Yes. It has no impact on dataframe.

Comment: So then this answer does not apply to the question and the one-liner doesn't solve the problem. The point isn't to generate a CSV; it's to replace the dataframe's headers with the values in the first row.

Comment: It replace the dataframe headers on pandas. The code itself is "df.", df is your dataframe reading the data from your csv file