# Why One Liner Result Is Different

Tags: python

While working with Fibonacci sequence:

```
a = 1
b = 3
a, b = b, a + b
print a, b
```

This properly results to `a = 3` and `b = 4`

Now if I would re-code it as:

```
a = 1
b = 3
a = b
b = a + b
print a, b
```

the resulting variable `b` is `6` instead of `4`.

What happens "behind of scenes" when one-liner `a, b = b, a + b` is used?

Comment: b =3 #value of b is 3. a = b #value of a is 3. 3+3 is 6. What more do you want?

Comment: In the second example `b = b+b` because `a` gets the value of `b` one line earlier. In a one-liner it doesn't happen.

Comment: when you write a = b    you just assign b's value to variable a.

Comment: It was quite surprising to find that `a,b=b,a+b` is not just the "one-liner". The syntax changes the way the code is being evaluated.

Comment: Note that even the order of the variables is important. See [Tuple unpacking order changes values assigned](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34171348)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a combination of [tuple packing and sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). It is parsed the same way as

```
(a, b) = (b, a + b)
```

The tuple on the right side is evaluated before the assignment, which is why the "old" values are used.

Answer (score 0):

You said
`b = 3`
and then
`a = b`
and then
`b = a + b`
which is the same as
`b = b + b`
or, in other words,
`b = 3 + 3`,
so `b = 6`.

The first one is like `a, b = 3, 1 + 3` or `a, b = 3, 4` so `b = 4`.

Answer (score 0):

`(` `)` don't make the sequence a tuple, rather `,`s do.

```
a, b = b, a + b # => (a,b) = (a, a+b) if written with brackets
```

So, it's standard tuple unpacking. But the thing with *names* `a` and `b` on the lest is they are names of *different* objects now, namely those known as `b` and result of `a+b` previously. This behavior is partly due to the fact that variable names in python are *names*, not boxes,like in C, that store values.