# reverse a linked list with multiple assignment - not all assignment orders work?

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list, multiple-assignment

exactly the same as [Reversing a LinkedList in with multiple assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017121/reversing-a-linkedlist-in-with-multiple-assignment)

but if you try:

`pre, node, node.next = node, node.next, pre`

it does not work! (getting `NoneType` has no attribute next)

both:

`pre, node.next, node = node, pre, node.next`

and

`node.next, pre, node = pre, node, node.next`

work. why is the top one wrong? I thought that multiple assignment relieves me from the need to think about the proper order (or to think at all :)

---

EDIT:

I'll narrow it down:

```py
if node:
   node.next, node = None, node.next
   #node, node.next = node.next, None # comment the previous line and uncomment this - boom!
```

I always thought that these lines are equivalent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that one of your receiving variables performs an indirection that is based on a value being assigned.   The multi-assignment logic saves you from thinking about the right side because it automatically creates temporary storage for the source values.  This does not apply to the left side of the assignment however.

So, the order in which `node` is being assigned matters because of the assignment to `node.next`.

Comment: so it saves me from thinking with my right brain but not from thinking with my left brain? :)

Comment: What’s interesting is that this *could* be made to work, even though the language doesn’t have pointers to *variables* like in C.  Each assignment could be preevaluated to one of the canonical forms `x`, `x.a`, or `x[k]` with `x` and (as appropriate) `a` or `k` saved just like the values on the right-hand side.  That might, though, be even more surprising in the cases where it matters…

Comment: I guess it's a design decision.  There are use cases where not pre-determining the target recipients may be what's expected/required.  In any case knowing how it behaves is the key to obtaining the desired results (e.g. assignments to a property with a setter).