# Unable to comprehend this behaviour of swapping statement in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, logic

I was solving a question on leetcode. "41. First Missing Positive"

For swapping, when I used

```
nums[i],nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1],nums[i]
```

I got TLE (time limit exceeded).

But

```
nums[nums[i]-1],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[nums[i]-1]
```

is working perfectly.

This is not just the case with leetcode.

I tried to understand the difference, spent 1 hour on the problem.
And then reached out to Google bard and Chatgpt. Both struggled.

After spending lots of time, I got an answer "Given that both codes share the same logic and conditional statements, it remains puzzling why Code 1 is exhibiting an issue, especially in the scenario you described with the infinite loop."

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def firstMissingPositive(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        i,n = 0,len(nums)

        while i<n:
            if nums[i]>0 and nums[i]<=n and nums[nums[i]-1]!=nums[i]:
                #nums[i],nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1],nums[i]
                nums[nums[i]-1],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[nums[i]-1]

            else:
                i+=1
        for i in range(n):
            if nums[i]!=i+1:
                return i+1
        return n+1
```

The commented out statement is giving TLE , but second one is working fine. Can someone please explain, what is causing this? Is `a,b=b,a` and `b,a=a,b` different?

I also defined the function in Python IDLE, added a print statement below the swapping statement, and it got stuck in infinite loop again.

[Defined function in Python IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/436Dm.png)

[Output (infinite loop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thBah.png)

[TLE with first statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiyGY.png)

[Accepted with second statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQG2n.png)

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i77761572/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the *order* in which the assignment happens changes.

In the first case,

```
nums[i],nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1],nums[i]
```

*First*, `nums[i]` gets updated, then, `nums[num[i] -1]` gets updated, so *that second assignment target is affected by the first change*.

So it is equivalent to something like:

```
temp = nums[nums[i]-1],nums[i] 
nums[i] = temp[0]
nums[nums[i]-1] = temp[1]
```

In the second case,

```
temp = nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1]
nums[nums[i]-1] = temp[0]
nums[i] = temp[1]
```

*First* `nums[nums[i]-1]` gets updated, then `nums[i]` gets updated. The `nums[i]` inside `nums[nums[i]-1]` will be different than the first case.

So, if you look at the [documentation for assignment statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) they give a simple example of what is going on:

> Although the definition of assignment implies that overlaps between
> the left-hand side and the right-hand side are ‘simultaneous’ (for
> example `a, b = b, a` swaps two variables), overlaps *within* the
> collection of assigned-to variables occur left-to-right, sometimes
> resulting in confusion. For instance, the following program prints `[0, 2]`:

```
x = [0, 1]
i = 0
i, x[i] = 1, 2         # i is updated, then x[i] is updated
print(x)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy the only one off the top of my head is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally but IMO it doesn't directly address what is going on here, which seems to be unintuitive enough to warrant a section in the docs

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34171348/12671057) maybe (too sleepy to read it now...)