# Pandas indexing before 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a very weird indexing problem with pandas and the arch package. Please see below.

```
      2018-07-01 12:00:00  0.13140109854255924
0     2018-07-01 16:00:00             0.144556
1     2018-07-01 20:00:00             0.158099
2     2018-07-02 00:00:00             0.171786
3     2018-07-02 04:00:00             0.185339
4     2018-07-02 08:00:00             0.198468
5     2018-07-02 12:00:00             2.513214
```

notice anything wrong. Its driving me doolaly cos I can't get rid of it. Now see:

> df = df.iloc[1:,:]
>
> print(df)

```
      2018-07-01 12:00:00  0.13140109854255924
2     2018-07-02 00:00:00             0.171786
3     2018-07-02 04:00:00             0.185339
4     2018-07-02 08:00:00             0.198468
5     2018-07-02 12:00:00             2.513214
6     2018-07-02 16:00:00             2.157013
```

now look at

> df2 = pd.Series(range(100))
>
> print(df2)

```
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      5
```

> df3 = df.loc[df2.index,:]
>
> print(df3)

```
    2018-07-01 12:00:00  0.13140109854255924
0                   NaN                  NaN
1                   NaN                  NaN
2   2018-07-02 00:00:00             0.171786
3   2018-07-02 04:00:00             0.185339
4   2018-07-02 08:00:00             0.198468
5   2018-07-02 12:00:00             2.513214
6   2018-07-02 16:00:00             2.157013
```

I think it may be the package. Because df2 above looks ok. So here is my code for  generating df.

```
from arch import arch_model

am = arch_model(series)
res = am.fit(update_freq=5,disp='off')


sres = res.resid/res.conditional_volatility
vola = res.conditional_volatility
print(sres)
sres.to_csv(filename,index=True)
```

Comment: Are you reading data from a CSV file? It seems the first line in your dataset was interpreted as column titles. Also please provide more useful descriptions besides "notice anything weird?" and "it drives me doolaly". Useful descriptions are "I expected X but got Y"

Comment: Ok. I apologise for the dramatic language. But I think my post was descriptive enough. And yes I am reading from csv.

Comment: What is the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: Hi, I found this work around. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/python-pandas-replacing-header-with-top-row, not sure its a complete solution but it works.