# Spliting using pandas with comma followed by space or just a space

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df

```
"33, BUffalo New York"
"44, Charleston North Carolina "
], columns=['row'])
```

My intention is to split them by a comma followed by a space or just a space like this

```
33 Buffalo New York
44 Charleston North Carolina
```

My command is as follows:

```
df["row"].str.split("[,\s|\s]", n = 2, expand = True)
```

```
0   STD     City State
1   33      Buffalo New York
2   44      Charleston North Carolina
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), your split command does what it should if you just remove the square brackets. This command works:

```
new_df = df["row"].str.split(",\s|\s", n=2, expand=True)
```

Note: if your cities have spaces in them, then this will fail. It works if the state has a space in it, because the `n=3` ensures that exactly 3 columns result.
The only part that you are missing is to set the first row as the header. As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328974/12568761), you can use pandas' [iloc command](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
new_df.columns = new_df.iloc[0]
new_df = newdf[1:]
print (new_df)
# 0 STD        City            State
# 1  33     BUffalo         New York
# 2  44  Charleston  North Carolina
```