# Get Max Value of a Row in subset of Column respecting a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| FakeDist | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 14 | 17 | 29 | 31 | 34 | 32 | 31 | 21 | 17 | 18 |
| 2 | 12 | 13 | 12 | 16 | 30 | 33 | 37 | 32 | 32 | 15 | 42 |
| 3 | 40 | 16 | 29 | 31 | 36 | 32 | 30 | 19 | 16 | 15 | 12 |
| 4 | 12 | 14 | 12 | 28 | 28 | 30 | 29 | 27 | 16 | 18 | 33 |
| 5 | 12 | 13 | 16 | 17 | 28 | 32 | 33 | 30 | 29 | 17 | 35 |

I want to add a column that will be the Column_Name of the Maximum Value per Row.
I did that with:

```
df['MaxVal_Dist'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

Which gives me this df:

| FakeDist | -5 | -4 | ... | MaxVal_Dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 14 | ... | -5 |
| 2 | 12 | 13 | ... | 5 |
| 3 | 40 | 16 | ... | -5 |
| 4 | 12 | 14 | ... | 5 |
| 5 | 12 | 13 | ... | 5 |

But my real end point would be to add an if condition. I want the Max Value for the column where 'FakeDist' is between -2 and 2. To have the following result:

| FakeDist | -5 | -4 | ... | MaxVal_Dist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 37 | 14 | ... | 0 |
| 2 | 12 | 13 | ... | 1 |
| 3 | 40 | 16 | ... | -1 |
| 4 | 12 | 14 | ... | 0 |
| 5 | 12 | 13 | ... | 1 |

I did try to look at how to add a `df.apply` but couldn't find how to make it work.
I have a "work around" idea that would be to store a subset of column (from -2 to 2) in a new dataframe, create my new column to get the max there, and then add that result column to my initial dataframe but it seem to me to be a very not elegant solution and I am sure there is much better to do.

**I would be really glad to learn the elegant way to do that from you !**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `boolean indexing` with `loc` to filter the columns in the range `-2` to `2`, then use `idxmax` along `axis=1`:

```
c = df.columns.astype(int)
df['MaxVal_Dist'] = df.loc[:, (c >= -2) & (c <= 2)].idxmax(1)
```

Result:

```
FakeDist  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4   5 MaxVal_Dist
1         37  14  17  29  31  34  32  31  21  17  18           0
2         12  13  12  16  30  33  37  32  32  15  42           1
3         40  16  29  31  36  32  30  19  16  15  12          -1
4         12  14  12  28  28  30  29  27  16  18  33           0
5         12  13  16  17  28  32  33  30  29  17  35           1
```

Comment: This works perfectly for what I wanted to do ! Thanks Shubham. To all the people as lost as I was, it also works if your number have decimals. Also, make sure that your first row is the header ! Mine was not and so it initially didn't work. I followed this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/python-pandas-replacing-header-with-top-row)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`List comprehension`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
In [1159]: cols = [i for i in df.columns[1:] if -2 <= int(i) <= 2]

In [1161]: df['MaxVal_Dist'] = df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)

In [1162]: df
Out[1162]: 
   FakeDist  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1   2   3   4   5 MaxVal_Dist
0         1  37  14  17  29  31  34  32  31  21  17  18           0
1         2  12  13  12  16  30  33  37  32  32  15  42           1
2         3  40  16  29  31  36  32  30  19  16  15  12          -1
3         4  12  14  12  28  28  30  29  27  16  18  33           0
4         5  12  13  16  17  28  32  33  30  29  17  35           1
```

Comment: This also works perfectly for what I wanted to do ! Thanks Mayank. To all the people as lost as I was, it also works if your number have decimals. Also, make sure that your first row is the header ! Mine was not and so it initially didn't work. I followed this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/python-pandas-replacing-header-with-top-row)