# I got this error pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type KeyError: 'class' when I try to skip a row when loading a csv tabulated data file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, scikit-learn

```py
import pandas as pd #pandas working with tabular data as dataframes
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #scikit-learn, building custom ML models

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier

#df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv')
#df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv', header=None)
#df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv', skiprows=[0])
df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv', skiprows=[0], header=None)

#df[df['class']=='Happy']

X = df.drop('class', axis=1) # features
y = df['class'] # target value

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)

pipelines = {
    'lr':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression()),
    'rc':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RidgeClassifier()),
    'rf':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier()),
    'gb':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GradientBoostingClassifier()),
}

fit_models = {}

for algo, pipeline in pipelines.items():
    model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    fit_models[algo] = model
fit_models['rc'].predict(X_test)
```

```py
df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv')
```

If I read the entire data array from the csv, the first row is also read and it gives an error when trying to convert a str to an int

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3_Train_Custom_Model_Using_Scikit_Learn.py", line 71, in <module>
    model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x1'
```

Then try various ways to remove that row containing the column names, which possibly generates the error. So considering that the indices start from 0, I did the following:

With `df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv', skiprows=0)`, give me `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x1'`

And with

```py
#df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv', header=None) #Option 1
#df = pd.read_csv('coords.csv', skiprows=[0], header=None) #Option 2
```

Give me this extrange error with pandas:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyPC0\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 89, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'class'
```

I think that this pandas error is due to the fact that when omitting the row of column names associated with index 0, Pandas for some reason that I don't know tries to "find" the columns of that omitted row, and not being able to do it, it throws that error , which in the console looks like an exception from Pandas.

The "Pandas error" does not even indicate a line in the code, I have no idea what it could be, how could I solve it to be able to remove (though I'm really just skipping it) that line with the column names and be able to train the model with .fit ()?

the csv file open in Excel

[image]

the csv file open in the text editor

[image]

I'm not sure if the problem could be the csv itself, although I doubt it. Anyway, here I leave the code of the algorithm that I use to load the data in the csv, taking the comma as a delimiter

```py
pose = results.pose_landmarks.landmark

pose_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in pose]).flatten())

face = results.face_landmarks.landmark

face_row = list(np.array([[landmark.x, landmark.y, landmark.z, landmark.visibility] for landmark in face]).flatten())

row = pose_row+face_row
row.insert(0, class_name)

with open('coords.csv', mode='a', newline='') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: tried skiprows = 1?

Comment: @Jimmy With skiprows = 1 , this give me return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'class'

Comment: make sure your separator is correct (you can check separator by open csv file on notepad), for example on csv using ';' separator, then add it (sep =';').

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto There in the question I have attached a capture of the csv file that I use to try to train the model, and taking the comma symbol as a delimiter, you can see how at least in Excel the columns are correctly delimited (at least that seems to be).

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto I do not know if the fact that they are commas affects the loading of the data from the csv in the df variable, anyway edit my question and at the end of it attach the code that I use to create the csv file using the comma as delimiter `,`

Comment: I think the error is 'class' , 'x1', ... is not the header but more as row first. the column name is 'Column1' hence y  cannot equal to df['class']. you have to make the row first as header first. do you get what I mean?

Comment: can you try this solution in your code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/python-pandas-replacing-header-with-top-row

Comment: @Jimmy It tries to read the csv file with `df = pd.read_csv ('coords.csv')` to then use `df = df [1:]`, but it keeps getting the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x1' `

Comment: refer to answer by rgalbo . 3 line of code or ostrokach

Comment: @Jimmy You mean to read the file with `df = pd.read_csv ('coords.csv')`, then take the header with `new_header = df.iloc [0]`, then take the data out of that header and store it In a variable `df = df [1:]`, until then I understand how the following instruction `df.columns = new_header` would save the header row setting ?

Comment: I sugest you to save csv file by pandas module, because if I see the error was given (could not convert string to float: 'x1'), clearly The dataframes incorect, in this case only first column has delete. So use `header =[1]` because your csv have 2 header ([columns1,columns2,....] and [class, x1,x2]).

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto I also thought of an error in the delimiting frames of the data, although what makes me doubt is that Excel can separate them correctly, I tried what you said about putting the header with index 1 but it gave the error that you comment in your answer, Do you suggest that I regenerate the csv but with delimiters of `;` ?

Comment: Try to use `dataframe.to_csv()`, for example you have lib `dat = {'x1': pose.landmark.x, 'y1': pose.landmark.y, 'z1': pose.landmark.z, 'v1': pose.landmark.visibility,'x2': face.landmark.x, 'y2': face.landmark.y, 'z2': face.landmark.z, 'v2': face.landmark.visibility}` (acording to your script) do `df = pd.DataFrames(data)`, If you want to save it first do `df.to_csv('try.csv',sep = ';')` (I always using this separator). Compare to how you save your csv with csv library, this csv only have 1 header ([x1,y1,.....]), so `pandas.read_csv` header set as default at first row.

Comment: And if I look at your notepad, that's clearly no row has created, so you need to change how to save the csv file.

Comment: @WahyuHadinoto The problem is that there are too many landmarks, they are 501, and each one has a value of x, another value of y, a value of z, and a display value v, I don't know if I could use that

Comment: Just use loop for add more variable on dict data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your notepad, you can't just read it use `pandas` because not clearly what is the header of the data, and I assume this data just have 1 row (Because I don't see data from row of class and your just make the np array to a list can cause it).
Example of correct csv:
[image]
You can see clearly the first column indicate the data separate properly and can assume this data have more than 1 row. So difference from your csv.
So you need to try `pandas` to save your data. For example your `pose, face` data have n - pair data, the easy way to add all of the data is we can use loop to add to dict:

```
import pandas as pd
data_pose = {}
ind = 0
for landmark in pose:
    data_pose['x'+str(ind)] = landmark.x
    data_pose['y'+str(ind)] = landmark.y
    data_pose['z'+str(ind)] = landmark.z
    data_pose['v'+str(ind)] = landmark.visibility
    ind = ind+1
data_face = {}
ind = 0
for landmark in face:
    data_face['xx'+str(ind)] = landmark.x
    data_face['yy'+str(ind)] = landmark.y
    data_face['zz'+str(ind)] = landmark.z
    data_face['vv'+str(ind)] = landmark.visibility
    ind = ind+1
data = {**data_pose,**data_face}
df = pd.DataFrames(data)
df.to_csv('try.csv',sep=';')
```

And if you want to re-read csv file just do it like this :

```
df = pd.read_csv('try.csv',sep=';')
```

The header of df will be set default, in this case will take first row of your csv file. It will fix your `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x1'` error because this header will separate from your data.
Remember to make difference variable from `pose` and `face`, like `x` and `xx`.
But I prefer to use multiindex for this case.

Comment: I just tried that `df = pd.read_csv ('coords.csv', sep = ',', index_col = [0], header = [1])`, but with the comma separator, since all csv use the `,` as a separator and not the `;`, since in the csv writing code  `csv_writer = csv.writer (f, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"', quoting = csv .QUOTE_MINIMAL) `, however this gives me the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "3_Train_Custom_Model_Using_Scikit_Learn.py", line 43, in <module>
     X = df.drop ('class', axis = 1) # features raise KeyError (f "{labels [mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: "['class'] not found in axis"`

Comment: In this case, you need to try `pandas` to save your data as csv

Comment: Really thanks, I will try to try with it although I do not understand why the other fails, anyway, so as not to have to adapt the whole code, it would be more convenient to do it with the other

Answer (score 1):

By using answer from [Python Pandas Replacing Header with Top Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/python-pandas-replacing-header-with-top-row)

```
import pandas as pd #pandas working with tabular data as dataframes
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split #scikit-learn, building custom ML models

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, GradientBoostingClassifier

df = pd.read_csv('coo.csv')

df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0, :], inplace=True)
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace=True)


#df[df['class']=='Happy']

X = df.drop('class', axis=1) # features
y = df['class'] # target value

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1234)

pipelines = {
    'lr':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), LogisticRegression()),
    'rc':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RidgeClassifier()),
    'rf':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), RandomForestClassifier()),
    'gb':make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), GradientBoostingClassifier()),
}

fit_models = {}

for algo, pipeline in pipelines.items():
    model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    fit_models[algo] = model
fit_models['rc'].predict(X_test)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):  File "3_Train_Custom_Model_Using_Scikit_Learn.py", line 42, in <module>  X = df.drop('class', axis=1) # features   raise KeyError(f"{labels} not found in axis")  KeyError: "['class'] not found in axis"`

Comment: This give that error with the `class`

Comment: Edit my question and add a screenshot of the csv file in the text editor, and you can see the comma separations

Comment: Hurmm X= df.iloc[: , 1:] ? I have no idea. Because when I tried there are no error using Python version 3.7.8

Comment: I'm testing it with the same version as you, but it doesn't work for me. It's really complicated