# How to get "Excel" column name for headers in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that has 480 columns and one row which has the header's name. I want to get the excel column name for a specific header.
for e.g-

var1   var2   event5   event8   media5     retail6    event9    var10

Let's say, I need to locate the excel column namefor retail6(F Column in Excel). what is the best and easiest way of doing that?

output should be-
var1 A
var2 B
event5 C and so on

Comment: I think this answer might be the one you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328974/13734132

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer might be the one you are looking for:
stackoverflow.com/a/31328974/13734132

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to replace the headers. I want to get the excel column name of a particular header, for eg : Var1 is under Excel Column "A", var2 is under Excel Column "B" and so on. If I want to locate the excel column name for media5 header, it should return Excel Column name : E