# Rename of huge number of columns - python / pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, rename

I wonder how to change the names of columns which name has begin on "Unnamed:".
Want to replace those columns with years from 1960 to 2019.
Have you guys any idea how?

[image]

Comment: How are you creating your dataframe? Reading from csv? It seems like row number 2 is what you want as your column names?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post images, include the information as text (in code fences). If you're using a Pandas dataframe (please clarify by appropriate tags) use [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) with a suitable mapper and `axis=1`.

Comment: Tobias, yes form csv. And yes exactly about row number 2, I wanna to name columns as row 2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328974/14066512

Comment: You can use the header argument to `pd.read_csv(..., header=1)` to select a specific row to use for the column names. Alternatively, use `pd.read_csv(..., skiprows=1)` to skip the first row of the file. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `loop` over the columns and check if it needs to be renamed. This code assumes that they are in order of the year you want them.

```
year = 1960
for col in my_df.columns:
    if col.startswith('Unnamed'):
        my_df.rename(columns = {col :f'{year}'}, inplace = True)
        year += 1
```