# Pandas data frame index setting Key value error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below.

[image]

I need to set the 'xvalues' column as the index of this data frame.Below is my code.

```
df_thd_StepVF_funct_T.set_index('xvalues',inplace=True)
```

But this is giving me an error as shown below.May I know where I went wrong.

**KeyError: "None of ['xvalues'] are in the columns"**

Comment: There is no column named `'xvalues'`. Should be pretty obvious from your screenshot or by doing `print(df.columns)`

Comment: I think the error is quite clear... `xvalues` is not a column. Can you show the output of `df_thd_StepVF_funct_T.columns`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Replacing Header with Top Row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31328861/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new_header = df_thd_StepVF_funct_T.iloc[0]
df_thd_StepVF_funct_T = df_thd_StepVF_funct_T[1:]
df_thd_StepVF_funct_T.columns = new_header
```

Then try again on `df_thd_StepVF_funct_T`.