# Python - Return DataFrame Objects if column value is an Element of given Array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I am extracting a HTML Table from Web with Pandas.
In this result *(List of Dataframe Objects)* I want to return all Dataframes where the Cell Value is an Element of an given Array.

So far I am struggling to call **only one one column value** and not the whole Object.

Syntax of Table: *(the Header Lines are not extracted correctly so this i the real Output)*

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | Name | Number | Text |
| 09.09.2022 | Smith Jason | 3290 | Free Car Wash |
| 12.03.2022 | Betty Paulsen | 231 | 10l Gasoline |

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = f'https://some_website.com'

df = pd.read_html(url)

arr_Nr = ['3290', '9273']

def correct_number():
    for el in df[0][1]:
        if (el in arr_Nr):
            return True

def get_winner():
    for el in df:
        if (el in arr_Nr):
            return el

print(get_winner())
```

With the Function

```
correct_number()
```

I can output that there is a Winner, but not the Details, when I try to access

```
get_winner()
```

***EDIT***

So far I now think I got one step closer: The function read_html() returns a list of DataFrame Objects. In my example, there is only one table so accessing it via `df = dfs[0]` I should get the correct DataFrame Object.

But now when I try the following, the Code don't work as expected, there is no Filter applied and the Table is returned in full:

df2 = df[df.Number == '3290']
print(df2)

Comment: you need to set the first line as your header.. you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/python-pandas-replacing-header-with-top-row
Then you can access each column this way df.column_name

Comment: Thanks for that, I was able to define the regular headers with some details in read_html:dfs = pd.read_html(url,  header =0, flavor = 'bs4'). Now how can I access one column of a single DataFrame?

Comment: you can access the dataframe using df.column_name for an example if you want to access Date use df.Date and if you want to access a specific line in the column using the row index you can do this df.Date.loc[index]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i finally figured it out:

Pandas returned List of DataFrame Objects, in my example there is only one table, to access this Table aka the DataFrame Object I had to access it first.
Before I then could compare the Values, I parsed them to integers, Pandas seemed to extract them as char, so my Array couldn't compare them properly.

In the End the code looks way more elegant that I thought before:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = f'https://mywebsite.com/winners-2022'

dfs_list = pd.read_html(url,  header =0, flavor = 'bs4') 
df = dfs_list[0] 

winner_nrs = [3290, 843]

result = df[df.Losnummer.astype(int).isin(winner_nrs)]
```