# Processing a CSV file with multiple, independent headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new to python (and Stack Overflow in general) and I'm trying to process a CSV file that is made up of two sections, each with their own header row of different length.

The first section consists of only two rows: a header row with 13 columns and a second row containing data.

After two empty lines, section two begins with another header row, this time 42 entries long, followed by a variable amount of data rows.

Consider this (shortened) example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | File name | Date | Time | ID | Type |  |  |  |
| **2** | report.csv | 27.03.2024 | 11:15 | 12345 | Thing |  |  |  |
| **3** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **5** | No. | Device | Version | Readout date | Readout time | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| **6** | 1 | 2345678 | 10 | 26.03.2024 | 10:00 | 463 | 470 | 482 |
| **7** | 2 | 3456789 | 11 | 26.03.2024 | 11:00 | 298 | 340 | 363 |
| **8** | 3 | 4567890 | 12 | 26.03.2024 | 12:00 | 587 | 600 | 621 |
| **9** | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

What I'm trying to achieve is treating these sections as two independent things and create a `dict` for each, preferably without the need to create any "helper" files (like splitting it into two separate CSV files). So far I have tried a number of approaches using `csv.DictReader`, `pandas.read_csv` with a set `chunksize` or a list of row indexes for its `header` argument. I've been googling for the past hour but I can't seem to find anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: What do the empty rows look like in the .csv? Are they empty cells, so something like ",,,,,,,," when viewed as text, or are they just blank lines?

Comment: They are completely empty. All other entries are tab-separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily split this CSV using .iloc function
so first read your CSV as dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
my_csv = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv')
```

create 2 variables with where you will define parts of dataframe as new dataframe eg.:

```
df1 = my_csv[:3]
df2 = my_csv[5:]
```

if columns are not red well, you need to assign column names separately like:

```
df1.columns = ['No. Device', 'Version', 'Readout date', 'Readout time', 'Value 1',  'Value 2',  'Value 3']
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `pd.read_csv` should throw an error if you have a varying number of columns

Comment: Yes to what Plagon said: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 13 fields in line 5, saw 42

Comment: I was able to circumvent the error by supplying temporary column labels to the read_csv method through `names=range(42)`, truncating the resulting dataframe using `df1 = my_csv.truncate(after=1)` followed by `df1 = df1.truncate(after=12, axis=1)` and replacing the temporary column names with the dataframe's first row by using the approach from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328861/replacing-header-with-top-row . This might not be the most elegant solution, but it was easy to understand to me as a beginner and does what it is supposed to do. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, yeah Plagon is right, forgot that you have not even number of columns in both sections. Glad that you overcome it. If it works, it works, don't bother about elegant way, especially if you're begginer! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>python 3.11.5</kbd>
<kbd>pandas 2.2.1</kbd>

We can use `csv.reader` to load the data in order.

Let's say we have this data in a csv file:

```
import csv, io

raw_data = '''File name,Date,Time,ID,Type
report.csv,27.03.2024,11:15,12345,Thing


No.,Device,Version,Readout date,Readout time,Value 1,Value 2,Value 3
1,2345678,10,26.03.2024,10:00,463,470,482
2,3456789,11,26.03.2024,11:00,298,340,363
3,4567890,12,26.03.2024,12:00,587,600,621
'''

data = csv.reader(io.StringIO(raw_data))
```

We create the first dictionary directly by reading the first 2 lines:

```
first_table = dict(zip(next(data), next(data)))
```

To get the next one, we can use `pandas.DataFrame`, but first we have to skip empty lines:

```
import pandas as pd

for line in data:
    if line:
         break
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=line)
```

Or, to play it safe:

```
for line in data:
    if any(cell.strip() for cell in line):
         break
else:
    raise(ValueError('No data for the second table found'))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=line)
```

If Pandas can't be used, we can try creating a dictionary as before by zipping header names and the rest of the data:

```
for headers in data:
    if any(cell.strip() for cell in headers):
        break
columns = zip(*data)
second_table = dict(zip(headers, columns))
```

---

Code to experiment with:

```
from csv import reader
from itertools import takewhile

data = reader(open('data.csv'))
tables = []

for record in data:
    if record:   
        headers = record
        rows = takewhile(bool, data)
        columns = map(list, zip(*rows))
        tables.append(dict(zip(headers, columns)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it will be separate by two empty lines, you can just load the file as a string and split them before you pass them to a csv reader.

Sample file:

```
col_1,col2_,col_3
1,2,3


c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('file.csv') as f:
    files = f.read().split('\n\n')

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file))
    print(df.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

Result:

```
{'col_1': [1], 'col2_': [2], 'col_3': [3]}
{'c1': [1], 'c2': [2], 'c3': [3], 'c4': [4], 'c5': [5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

using the standard csv (not pandas) you can skip as many header lines you need using the 'next' command in a for-loop. The code below shows how to open a file and skip the number of lines you need (5 in that example)

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'), delimiter=';')

for row in range(5):
    next(reader) # skip header line

# start displaying for the 6th row
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

if the header had a variable number of row, you could then loop in the reader file and detect the line you need which contains the actual header of your data by checking the value of the 1st column to search for the header name :

```
import csv 

reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv'), delimiter=';')

for row in reader:
    # check the row is not empty and check for 1st column (row[0])
    if row !=[] and row[0] == 'first_col_header':
         print (row)
```